# How can I use the bind command for remapping keybindings for screen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen, bind

I am trying to use the bind command to remap `C-a` keybinding in screen, as I use `C-a` for getting to the beginning of a line.

According to the screen documentation I should use the `bind` command for remapping keybindings. When I looked at the man page for `bind`, it says that `bind` is used for binding a name to a socket. I think that is a different bind.

I looked up examples for rebinding using `bind` but it looks like the `bind` command being used is different from the one described in the man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to remap the default key combination `CRTL + a` to another one like `CTRL + j`, which is pretty common, in my ubuntu 18.04 I just created a file under my user's home directory and put a line like below in it:

> `camaleon@ubuntu-server:~$ cat ~/.screenrc
>   escape ^Jj`

Now next time you run `screen` command you can press `CTRL + j`. However the default it's still working but remember you can easily jump to the beginning of the line by pressing `CTRL + a + a`.

**Note:** You can also test it at runtime inside a screen session by typing `CTRL + a` and then `: escape ^Jj`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That helped. But I would like to know how the bind command works

Comment: Have you read the official doc? See wiki [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) to see if you can find something.